# How do I specify the width of elements within a Flutter list that is expanded?

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

The below code represents a list of items where the list should be full width but elements inside the list may not be. Flutter seems to be ignoring my width constraint on the `SizedBox` and forcing it to fully expand.

```
class ExampleBadListWidth extends StatelessWidget {
  List<String> things = [
    "1: This is a really really really really really really really  really really really  long thing",
    "2: This is a really really really really really really really  really really really  long thing",
    "3: This is a really really really really really really really  really really really  long thing"
  ];

  ExampleBadListWidth();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(children: [
      Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: things.length,
        itemBuilder: _thingBuilder,
      ))
    ]));
  }

  Widget _thingBuilder(context, index) {
    return SizedBox(width: 100, child: Text(things[index]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can wrap `SizedBox` with `Center` or `Align`

code snippet

```
Widget _thingBuilder(context, index) {
    return Center(
      child: SizedBox(
          width: 100,
          child: Text(things[index])),
    );
  }
```

or

```
 Widget _thingBuilder(context, index) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: SizedBox(
          width: 100,
          child: Text(things[index])),
    );
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExampleBadListWidth extends StatelessWidget {
  List<String> things = [
    "1: This is a really really really really really really really  really really really  long thing",
    "2: This is a really really really really really really really  really really really  long thing",
    "3: This is a really really really really really really really  really really really  long thing"
  ];

  ExampleBadListWidth();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(children: [
      Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: things.length,
        itemBuilder: _thingBuilder,
      ))
    ]));
  }

  Widget _thingBuilder(context, index) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: SizedBox(
          width: 100,
          child: Text(things[index])),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: ExampleBadListWidth(),
    );
  }
}
```